# Present Perfect vs Past Simple double time marker

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

I need some explanation when to use present or past in such examples:

> 1. In March this year he was seen or has been seen?
> 2. This week 2 days ago he has done it or did it?
> 3. 2 days ago this week he was asked or has been asked?

Comment: Your examples are not grammatical, but generally In March, two days ago would take simple past. There is no such thing as two days ago this week. Two days ago is by definition in a particular week.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the time phrases in the sentences.

In March.  2 days ago.

If they confine  the action to a particular time in the past, excluding the present, then a present perfect construction is not possible.

The presence of "this week" and "this year" does not connect the time involved to the present.   In fact, those phrases are not quite idiomatic in conjunction with "ago".

We can say  "A year ago next Friday" to mean "come Friday, it will be the one-year anniversary of" something. But even there, "ago" confines the action to the past, excluding the present, making the present perfect unviable.

> It will be a year ago next Friday that the river *flooded*.

Comment: This year I was in (/to) Spain? as I remember this week this year its pres perfect